# Subfolder routing doesn't work while angularjs works with spring

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using spring and angular js in my project. In spring I set the view resolver as follows,

```
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");

    return viewResolver;

}
```

In angularjs ,I'm trying to route views/subview/test.html. Code as follows,

```
$stateProvider

        .state("test", {url: "/test", templateUrl: "subview/test.html"});
});
```

Here the subview is the child folder of view folder.Since I set the view resolver to view folder only it not supports the view/subview/test.html.

Is it possible to setPrefix to all subfolders? If not, suggest other ways to handle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

no you will need to set the full path each time - the path is relative to the top level html page the app is running in - you could of course use variables to manage this e.g.

```
var baseTemplatePath = "/WEB-INF/views/";

$stateProvider
    .state("test", {url: "/test", templateUrl: baseTemplatePath + "subview/test.html"});
});
```

you could also put the variable in a higher level service for access everywhere.

```
angular.app("yourApp")
    .service("pathService", function() {
        return {
            baseTemplatePath: "/WEB-INF/views/" 
        };
    });
```

and then use (making sure you have injected the pathService):

```
$stateProvider
    .state("test", {url: "/test", templateUrl: pathService.baseTemplatePath + "subview/test.html"});
});
```

Comment: It works fine with angularjs but if coupled with spring it does not work. Moreover,I think the problem lies in the ViewResolver of spring rather than angularjs.